# Amazon EC2 instance doesn't run codeigniter application after installing php gd library

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-ec2, php-gd

I'm migrating a codeigniter application to amazon. I noticed that the captcha is not displaying and after search I found out that php gd library must be installed. The instance runs php 5.5.38 so I installed it this way

```
sudo yum install php55-gd
```

I've checked like this

```
if(extension_loaded('gd')){
    echo 'yes';
}
else{
    echo 'no';
}
```

and the result is 'yes'

using phpinfo() I found that it has been installed but the codeigniter application stopped working and the page doesn't display anything, it just keeps loading until I get max execution time error.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had to edit the helper to create random characters as I found that "random_int" function is not working